# When doing custom HTTP authentication and methods, what's the correct order of operations?

Tags: python, django, http

I have a Django application which liberally uses `django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required()` and also `django.views.decorators.http.require_http_methods()`. The former is a decorator which checks whether the current user is logged in, and redirects them (with code 302, IIRC) to the login page if not logged in. The latter is a decorator which examines the request method, and returns 405 (method not implemented) if the method isn't in the passed-in list. So, as an example, a view function might look like:

```
@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST", "DELETE"])
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Here's the problem: Many of these views do internal permission checks which return 403 (forbidden) if the user lacks sufficient permissions for the resource. According to my research, this is bad, because 403 needs to happen *before* examining whether the method is correct. However, without `login_required()`, I would have to open-code the user checks as well in my views.

Has anybody else experienced this? Is there a correct answer? I know it's cheating, but is it unacceptable to check methods, then do the login redirect, then finally check user permissions, or do I need to restructure these views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure about the 'correctness' of your order, but for any sort of complex view permission scheme I would highly recommend writing your own custom middleware to take care of view authentication / permissions. Rather than decorate every view with `@login_required` I always just take care of it in my own middleware.

You can also write your own view decorator(s) (which may or may not take arguments) and get exactly the behavior you want for different views.

Comment: The permissions required for each view are totally view-specific. Middleware would not be the right place and neither would decorators. I need to have the logged-in user, I need to be confident the user actually exists, and I have to do it *after* login_required, or do the login redirect myself.

Comment: I would just implement the login redirect in middleware- then you can do whatever authentication you want afterwards (in middleware or the views).

Comment: Doesn't that get icky since the middleware is always run but most views don't require login?

Comment: That's where I can create my own `@no_auth` decorator, or you can also pass a `auth=False` kwarg from your urls that the middleware can check for. I have used both techniques.

Comment: Generally I have used it on projects that require some type of auth on almost every view, so that may not be the best solution for you.